# How to download youtube autogenerated captions without yt-dlp?

Tags: youtube, caption, yt-dlp

There are [many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611397/how-to-extract-closed-caption-transcript-from-youtube-video) to download youtube captions, but they do not work for **autogenerated** captions.

I can download autogenerated captions with [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp), for example:

```bash
yt-dlp --skip-download --write-subs --write-auto-subs --sub-langs "ru-en" -P "/Users/user/Downloads" "https://youtu.be/PkZNo7MFNFg"
```

But how to do it without yt-dlp?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you don't want to use `yt-dlp` at all or if you don't want to use it just for downloading. You can use `yt-dlp` to find the download address and then download the subtitles either with your browser or with `wget`, for example.
To determine the URL, you must use the `--dump-json` option which allows you to obtain all the information from the video.

`yt-dlp --write-auto-subs "https://youtu.be/PkZNo7MFNFg" --dump-json  > info.json`

Edit this file, and go to the `automatic_captions` section, then `ru-en` and there you have the 5 download addresses for the 5 available formats.
For example for the `vtt` format:

`https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?v=PkZNo7MFNFg&ei=AsvXZdHVEo6zp-oPmtyE2AE&caps=asr&opi=112496729&xoaf=5&hl=en&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1708666226&sparams=ip%2Cipbits%2Cexpire%2Cv%2Cei%2Ccaps%2Copi%2Cxoaf&signature=09860E14932DDDAB486742638E9A499216DE19AE.B300E3CDF4AC749907DF14051439C79790542CC1&key=yt8&lang=en&tlang=ru-en&fmt=vtt`

You can download it with `wget`:

`wget "https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?v=PkZNo7MFNFg&ei=AsvXZdHVEo6zp-oPmtyE2AE&caps=asr&opi=112496729&xoaf=5&hl=en&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1708666226&sparams=ip%2Cipbits%2Cexpire%2Cv%2Cei%2Ccaps%2Copi%2Cxoaf&signature=09860E14932DDDAB486742638E9A499216DE19AE.B300E3CDF4AC749907DF14051439C79790542CC1&key=yt8&lang=en&tlang=ru-en&fmt=vtt"`

or directly in the browser.